Turing Machine - Finding k-th element and move it to the front of the tape
I am trying to solve the following Turing machine challenge:

The number choice function
The number choice function is defined as follows.
INPUT: a sequence , 1, 2,...,  where

 is a positive integer.

For each ,  is a nonnegative integer.

All these numbers are encoded in unary using repetition of the letter a, with the letter b used as a separator (in effect, playing the role of the commas). So the input sequence , 1, 2,...,  is encoded as the string
      aba1ba2b....a


OUTPUT: , i.e. the -th of the  numbers.

This also is encoded in unary in the same way, but without any b at the end. So the output  is encoded as the string a.
Recall the definition of the output of a Turing machine from Lecture 18 slide 28 (or Course Notes §18.8 p. 223). Once the machine enters the Accept state, it does not matter what comes after the leftmost blank cell; those later cells are not considered to be part of the output string.

Some examples inputs and outputs:



input sequence
input encoded as string
output number
output encoded as string




3,1,5,2
aaababaaaaabaa
2
aa


2,4,7,0,3
aabaaaabaaaaaaabbaaa
7
aaaaaaa


1,0,1
abba
0
ε [first tape cell must be empty]


1,3,2,0
abaaabaab
3
aaa


3,3,2,0
aaabaaabaab
0
ε [first tape cell must be empty]


0,1,5,2
babaaaaabaa
undefined
crash: invalid input, k = 0


4,1,5,2
aaaababaaaaabaa
undefined
crash: invalid input, k > n



Notes:

Any input string that is not of the specified form should be rejected, by crashing. Examples of situations that must lead to a crash include:  = 0;  > .
You can, and should, have extra letters in your tape alphabet that are not in the input alphabet {a,b}


Question Image
I managed to cancel each initial a with each b by using the marking symbol technique, where for each read of a from , it will write it as A and go right to find b. If b is found, then write it as B and go back to find A. In this case, I can keep track of each A and B.
But at the end, when there are no more A and B, I have no idea how to go to the -th element and output the value, which would mean I had to somehow move that element to the front of the tape.
How can I achieve that?
p/s: I am using a Tuatara Simulator, which has a tape that extends infinitely only to the right. The head starts at the extreme left side of the tape.

So when there are no more as from the starting k section (as you've marked them all as A), can't you then keep moving your head to the right until you either find a lowercase b or empty cell, that means that the as to the left of that lowercase b/ε will be your k-th element.  You can set this cell to ε and then continue moving your head left along the lowercase as until you find an uppercase B, you can set that and all cells to its left to ε until you hit an empty cell.

@NickParsons, from what I learned it should be "When a Turing machine accepts an input string, its output is deemed to be the string that's on the tape at the time of acceptance, up to but not including the first blank cell."
Meaning from my example, the output should be aa_(from here onwards can have any symbols/letters).
I have no idea how to move the 'aa' to the front.

I don’t think you need to move it to the “front”, as the “front” would be where the first non empty cell is on the tape (I imagine), so clearing all the cells before “aa” should achieve that? To have an empty cell after “aa”, what I described above should achieve that: “You can set this cell to ε and then continue moving your head left along the lowercase as until you find an uppercase B, you can set that and all cells to its left to ε until you hit an empty cell”

I think I get what you mean, but I am not sure if my Tuatara Simulator has the function where it will recognise 'aa' as the front. For example if the output is "aaa__" I am not sure if the simulator will change it to "aa____". This simulator is developed from my university. But still thanks for the tips. I'll continue exploring the simulator and come back if I met any difficulties. Cheers.

You can keep track of the decreasing number of  by mapping each a that belongs to the encoding of  with a b. The idea to mark the characters that belong to such a pair is a good one. Once you have no more (unmarked) a left over, you can start to delete characters up until (and including) the first unmarked b. The a that follow should stay. Finally delete any characters that follow that series of a.
This approach would actually select the k+1th number, so just delete the first a without mapping it to a b to compensate for that.
You mentioned in comments that you are using a one-sided Turing Machine, where it is infinite to the right, but has a start at the left, where also the head starts. As you indicated that the expected output should be left-aligned at the start of the tape, you'll need some extra states and transitions to "move" the found sequence of a to the left. You can do this in different ways. One is to delete the rightmost a and write one at the left side of the sequence. Repeat this until you arrive at the start of the tape, which we could mark with a letter "A".
I would also wipe out the a that belong to  instead of marking them with an uppercase, as in the end you'll want to delete or replace those anyway.
Here is a possible transition table:



state
read
write
move head
next state




start
a
A
right
get


start
b or _

right
reject


get
a
_
right
findb


get
B
_
right
wipe


get
b
_
right
keep


findb
a or B

right
findb


findb
b
B
left
rewind


findb
_

left
reject


rewind
a or B

left
rewind


rewind
_

right
get


wipe
a or B
_
right
wipe


wipe
b
_
right
keep


wipe
_

left
reject


keep
a

right
keep


keep
_

left
pickup


keep
b
_
right
trim


trim
a or b
_
right
trim


trim
_

left
pickup


pickup
a
_
left
roll


pickup
_

left
pickup


pickup
A
_

accept


roll
a

left
roll


roll
_
a
right
right


right
a

right
right


right
_

left
pickup


roll
A
a

accept



The initial state is "start" and a blank is represented by "_". If the input has a solution, the final state will be "accept".
Here is a runnable implementation with that transition table:


createTuring({
    transitions: [
        { state: "start",  read: "a",   write: "A", move: "R", nextState: "get"    },
        { state: "start",  read: "b_",              move: "R", nextState: "reject" },
        { state: "get",    read: "a",   write: "_", move: "R", nextState: "findb"  },
        { state: "get",    read: "B",   write: "_", move: "R", nextState: "wipe"   },
        { state: "get",    read: "b",   write: "_", move: "R", nextState: "keep"   },
        { state: "findb",  read: "aB",              move: "R", nextState: "findb"  },
        { state: "findb",  read: "b",   write: "B", move: "L", nextState: "rewind" },
        { state: "findb",  read: "_",               move: "L", nextState: "reject" },
        { state: "rewind", read: "aB",              move: "L", nextState: "rewind" },
        { state: "rewind", read: "_",               move: "R", nextState: "get"    },
        { state: "wipe",   read: "aB",  write: "_", move: "R", nextState: "wipe"   },
        { state: "wipe",   read: "b",   write: "_", move: "R", nextState: "keep"   },
        { state: "wipe",   read: "_",               move: "L", nextState: "reject" },
        { state: "keep",   read: "a",               move: "R", nextState: "keep"   },
        { state: "keep",   read: "_",               move: "L", nextState: "pickup" },
        { state: "keep",   read: "b",   write: "_", move: "R", nextState: "trim"   },
        { state: "trim",   read: "ab",  write: "_", move: "R", nextState: "trim"   },
        { state: "trim",   read: "_",               move: "L", nextState: "pickup" },
        { state: "pickup", read: "a",   write: "_", move: "L", nextState: "roll"   },
        { state: "pickup", read: "_",               move: "L", nextState: "pickup" },
        { state: "pickup", read: "A",   write: "_",            nextState: "accept" },
        { state: "roll",   read: "a",               move: "L", nextState: "roll"   },
        { state: "roll",   read: "_",   write: "a", move: "R", nextState: "right"  },
        { state: "right",  read: "a",               move: "R", nextState: "right"  },
        { state: "right",  read: "_",               move: "L", nextState: "pickup" },
        { state: "roll",   read: "A",   write: "a",            nextState: "accept" },
    ],
    initState: "start",
    tape: "aaababaaaaabaa"
});
<script src="https://trincot.github.io/turing.js"></script>




Actually, I don't quite understand the logic on how this program can trace how many "a's" k has. My idea was mark one 'a', travel to find b and mark 'b' travel back to find 'a' and repeat the process. But your method shows that you somewhat mark all the 'a' to '_' since the start. Can you please explain a bit on the logic?

Also, is it possible to shift the output to the head of the tape? For example,
current: _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ a a _ _ _ _
desire: a a _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
The reason is because apparently, the simulator I am using does not recognise "current" as "desire"
My simulator will output the value as _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ a a _ _ _ _ _

Marking an a with _ works just the same. The difference is that you never have to replace those _ again, while in your approach you would still have to replace those A with _.

Apparently you are dealing with a Turing Machine that only has an infinite tape at the right side, but not at its left side. Is that so?

Yes, that is the case. my Turing Machine's tape is like this *_ _ _ _ _ _
Where the * is the not the starting of the tape. After the * then only it's the starting of the tape (first _)

OK, I updated my answer accordingly.

Alright, thanks @trincot. I will look through it again. You are a great help!

one question just pop out of my mind today. I looked back at the Turing Machine I build with my software, I've noticed that the direction of the last second state to the accept state (last state), I've left it blank. Is this correct or I should be introducing a direction for it too?

That is correct. Not all Turing Machines allow to not move the head, but if yours does, it is OK. See also Wikipedia: "Definitions in literature sometimes differ slightly, to make arguments or proofs easier or clearer, but this is always done in such a way that the resulting machine has the same computational power. For example, the set could be changed from {L,R} to {L,R,N}, where N ("None" or "No-operation") would allow the machine to stay on the same tape cell instead of moving left or right."

Alright, thanks!
